# I want to import tables from one sql server to another server using SSIS with loop

Tags: sql-server, ssis, import

I want to import table via SSIS, This package will execute like first it'll import first 10 tables once its imported then it'll start to import 10-20 tables, like a loop.

Can anyone explain me how can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried the foreach operator?

Comment: No, can you give me an example of it?

Comment: great blog on how to do it. For your case I'd look into using this blog but then using sql statements to loop through.  https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/implementing-foreach-looping-logic-in-ssis/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just don't even need a foreach loop and can use the `Rows per batch` setting of the destination :

[image]

But, well, I don't know how is your package so I'm not sure it fits...